# Read from a Text File only lines which starts with a specific string and display them in a form TextBox. (C#)

Tags: c#, file, text-files, text-extraction

I want to read some specific information from a `.txt` file and display that particular lines inside a `TextBox` in a [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) form application. The `.txt` file template looks like this:

info1: some characters here...

info2: some characters here...

info3: some characters

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5   Col6   Col7   Col8   Col9  
  <h1> ---------------------------------------------------------------  

   001   a      b     c    d      e       f       g      h  
   001   c      a     f    d      f       b       e      t  
   001   a      b     c    d      e       f       g      h  

   002   c      a     f    b      f       b       e      t  
   002   z      e     f    d      f       b       e      m          
   002   c      a     j    u      t       b       h      t  
   002   y      l     f    d      f       b       n      t  

   006   c      a     j    y      t       b       d      t   

   007   b      a     f    d      r       b       t      t  
   007   c      a     f    r      f       b       e      q  
   007   c      a     f    d      f       x       z      t  
   007   c      p     f    d      s       b       a      t  
   007   c      a     f    h      f       b       e      p  

   <h1>----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Additional info: numbers of lines similar to info3 is not fixed;

The functionality I need is to insert in a `TextBox` a the group of numbers which will correspond to the first columns (eg. 001) , And then display in another text box the header information of the file, the columns titles, and after that, Only the lines which starts with the number introduced excluding the others. How should a good solution for that would be?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you should use String.StartsWith

Example:

```
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\file.txt"))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();

        if (line.StartsWith("info"))
        {
            // do something
        }
    }

    reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick post ;) I don't know exactly how should I take, before and after the needed lines, the header information, and the last line (-----) also, in the same time...

Comment: @movi did you solve this problem? or do you need any more help?

Comment: Hi Felix, I think I solved the problem but not very elegand :) because i used multiple bloks similar to the one from your answer on the same file to obtain my information. I'm currently trying to merge all of this in a single block..